# Why am I getting "Can not read 'value' of undefined'?

Tags: javascript, angular

I get this error message and I am not sure why is that happening. Here is code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>New rule definition</h2>
  <hr>
  <form action="#">
    <select name="engines" #eng class="float-right" (change)="act">
      <option value="0">pick engine</option>
      <option *ngFor="let engine of engines" value='{{engine.engineId}}'>{{ engine.engineId }}</option>
    </select>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="description" class="col-form-label-lg">Description</label>
      <textarea name="description" (ngModel)="description" #description class="form-control" cols="30" rows="6"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="statement" class="col-form-label-lg">Statement</label>
      <textarea name="statement" (ngModel)="statement" #statement class="form-control" cols="30" rows="6"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" #act *ngIf="eng.value=='perseo-fe'">
      <label>Action</label>
      <br> Type:
      <input type="text" name="type" (ngModel)="actionType" #actionType />
      <br><br> Parameters:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" (ngModel)="actionName" #actionName />
      <br> Value:
      <select #actionValue (ngModel)="actionValue">
        <option value="true">true</option>
        <option value="false">false</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="type2" (ngModel)="typeValue" #typeValue placeholder="type" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="enable">
      <label for="enable" class="form-check-label">Enable</label>
    </div>
    <br>

    <button class="btn btn-primary"
      (click)="addRule(
        eng.value,
        description.value,
        statement.value,
        actionType.value,
        actionName.value,
        actionValue.value,
        typeValue.value
      )"
    >
      Add
    </button> &nbsp;
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

I want #act div to be invisible until user picks 'perseo-fe' from select. I managed to set it up, but when I try to send data I entered, I get 'undefined'. Strange thing is, when I remove `*ngIf`, it works?

Comment: Try to console.log(eng.value);

Comment: Well, obviously `eng` has not (yet) been defined.

Comment: try replacing `*ngIf="eng.value=='perseo-fe'"` with `[hidden]="*ngIf="eng.value!='perseo-fe'""`

Comment: Tried it, but it says that 'tag is closed unexpectedly'. :/

Comment: what is gaiz?  you seem to open all your posts with it - can be construed as quite rude unless you are trying to say guys, in which case can be quite sexist too as girls also use this site

Comment: Try using this :  `[hidden]="eng.value=='perseo-fe'"` instead of  `*ngIf="eng.value=='perseo-fe'"`

Comment: @Sanoj_V That did it. Just needed to switch == with !=. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

Try by putting "eng?.value".

The '?' won't trigger error if the value after your 'eng' is not yet defined.